# Any way to manually trigger highlighting of semantic symbol occurrence in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, when you place cursor inside a symbol (variables, functions, etc), all occurrence of the same symbol will be highlighted.

This feature is somewhat useful but annoying as well. Even I can make it less obtrusive by customizing the color theme in settings.json, it will suppress the selection highlighting when you select a variable by double clicking it with mouse cursor.

I've learned that I can completely disable this feature by adding *"editor.occurrencesHighlight":false* in settings.json, but this feature is still useful because it can label occurrences of a symbol with different color, to represent read/write status of each occurrence.

So my question is: is there any way to disable the automatic semantic matching feature, and only enable it manually with keyboard shortcuts or commands ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need textual matches, you can select some text use the `Select all occurrences of find match` command. This will select every occurrence of the selected text in the current document (and also create a cursor at it)

For symbol based information, try using the `Find all references` or `Peek references` commands. The flow is different but it gives the same information.

---

Alternatively, use an extension like [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.toggle)  to create a keyboard shortcut that toggles `editor.occurrencesHighlight`